# Hide .aspx from all web Pages

Tags: asp.net

Hi how i can hide .aspx from all my pages in my project

Comment: Do you mean hide the extension from the URL address?

Comment: yes like this Hide the extension from the URL address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new ASP.NET 4.0 Routing feature to avail of SEO-friendly URLs:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement an url rewriting mechanism to transform your urls.
See here for a simple tutorial:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement ASP.Net Routing. In ASP.Net Routing, you need to register routes for the pages for which you need to hide .aspx extension.

You can find more on ASP.Net routing at following blog series:

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-1.html

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-2.html

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-3.html

You can check the whole series, with various practical scenarios.